# C# chart tools for line graph using external txt file data

Tags: c#

I want to plot a line graph using c# chart tool, what I have is an  external txt file with data, such as:

> 1.2,1.0
>   1.3,1.5
>   1.4,2.0
>   1.5,2.5

I want to read those data and plot a line graph, I am stuck.

Below is my code. I am able to plot a line graph using a some automated data as shown.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();//creation and inialization of open file dialog 

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";// object of file dialog  sent to open file to default c drive
openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse txt File";// text to show on the bar

openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;// check whether file exit
openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;//check file path

openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";// the file default extensio
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";//filter by default to only txt files
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)// prompt for a file dialog
{
    double t, y, tIncr;
    chtSin.ChartAreas.Add("Default");
    // Add a series with some data points.
    Series sinSeries = new Series();
    sinSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    tIncr = 4 * Math.PI / 500;
    for (t = 0; t < 4 * Math.PI; t += tIncr)
    {
        y = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * t);
        sinSeries.Points.AddXY(t, y);
    }
    Series cosSeries = new Series();
    cosSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    tIncr = 4 * Math.PI / 500;
    for (t = 0; t < 4 * Math.PI; t += tIncr)
    {
        y = Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * t);
        cosSeries.Points.AddXY(t, y);
    }
    chtSin.Series.Add(sinSeries);
    chtSin.Series[0].Color = Color.Black;
    chtSin.Series.Add(cosSeries);
    chtSin.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
    chtSin.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Time";
    chtSin.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.00}";
    chtSin.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Volts";
    chtSin.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.00}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example, that should cover your scenario.
Of course, this is only example, but it can give you some ideas.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();//creation and inialization of open file dialog 

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\temp";// object of file dialog  sent to open file to default c drive
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse txt File";// text to show on the bar

            openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;// check whether file exit
            openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;//check file path

            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";// the file default extensio
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";//filter by default to only txt files
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)// prompt for a file dialog
            {
                //read selected text file
                string rawData = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //split into rows, delimited by NewLine (\r\n)
                string[] rows = rawData.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                //create dataTable
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("xValue", typeof(decimal));
                table.Columns.Add("yValue", typeof(decimal));

                foreach  (string row in rows)
                {
                    //split each row by ',' which will give array of two elements
                    string[] values = row.Split(',');
                    //put those elements as column values. Make additional operations here if needed (instead of table.Rows.Add(values))
                    // ie. 
                    //DataRow row = table.NewRow(); 
                    //row[0] = values[0].Trim();
                    //... 
                    table.Rows.Add(values);

                }

                //create series of data
                chtSin.Series.Add("series");
                //assign datatable column to series axis
                chtSin.Series["series"].XValueMember = "xValue";
                chtSin.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "yValue";
                //pass this DataTable as chart source
                chtSin.DataSource = table;
                //databind
                chtSin.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first you need to extract the data from the file. Then you need to add those points into the graph like you are doing with the automated data you already have.

So you want to grab the data and add it too a series with something like this:

```
//go to the file and extract the X and Y points
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());
string line = "";
Series filePoints = new Series();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != "")
{
    //find the dot so that you know were to split the string
    int split = line.IndexOf(".");
    float X = float.Parse(line.Substring(0, split)),
        Y = float.Parse(line.Substring(split + 1, line.Length - (split + 1)));

    //add the points
    filePoints.Points.AddXY(X, Y);
}
```

then you add the filepoints series to the chart. the code assumes that there are no formatting errors and each value is always has the same format ("X(comma)Y").

If this doesn't work for you comment bellow...